# Shifting a character from one place to another in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am coding a java program in which I have to accept a string and sort the words of the String if necessary and display the output of the sorted String inclusive the full stop which should be at the last position.
My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Stringop
{
    static String txt;
    void readString()//to accept the string
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)//to accept the string unless the string ends with a full stop '.'
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a Sentence:>");
            txt=in.nextLine();
            int lt=txt.length();
            if(txt.charAt(lt-1)=='.')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Stringop ob=new Stringop();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int w=1;//for continuous choice loop generarion
        while(true)
        {
            if(w==1)
            {
                ob.readString();
                String st=ob.sort(txt);
                String h=ob.cse_Convert(st);
                ob.display(h);
            }
            System.out.print("\n To Continue Press 1 else press 0");
            System.out.print("\n Do you want to Continue:");
            w=in.nextInt();
            if(w==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    String sort(String g)//Sorting of string alphabetically
    {
        g=g+" ";//giving a extra space to the string which helps in finding no. of words
        int c=0,k=0;String a="",st="",p="";
        for(int i=0;i<g.length();i++)
        {
            if(g.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                c++;//acting as a counter to count the no. of spaces=no. of words.
            }
        }
        String s[]=new String[c];
        for(int i=0;i<g.length();i++)
        {
            if(g.charAt(i)!=' '&&g.charAt(i)!='.')
            {
                a=a+g.charAt(i);
            }
            else if(g.charAt(i)==' '&&g.charAt(i)!='.')
            {
                s[k]=a;//Stroring of the words in array
                k++;//acts as an index value for the array
                a="";//re-initializes the String a to null.
            }
            else if(g.charAt(i)=='.')
                {
                    s[k]=a+g.charAt(i);
                }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<c-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c-1-i;j++)
            {
                    if((s[j].compareTo(s[j+1]))>0)
                {
                    p=s[j];
                    s[j]=s[j+1];
                    s[j+1]=p;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            st=st+s[i]+" ";
        }
        return st;
    }

    public String cse_Convert(String g)//for Case conversion
    {
        String h="",p="";
        for(int i=0;i<g.length();i++)
        {
            char s=g.charAt(i);
            if(s>=65&&s<=90)
            {
                int a=(int)s+32;
                char t=(char)a;
                h=h+t;
            }
            else if(s>=97&&s<=122)
            {
                int a=(int)s-32;
                char t=(char)a;
                h=h+t;
            }
            else if(s==' ')
            {
                h=h+" ";
            } 
            else if(s=='.')
            {
                h=h+s;
            }
            else
            {
                h=h+s;
            }
        }
        return h;
    }
    void display(String y)//displaying the sorted string
    {
        System.out.print("New String:>"+y);
    }
}
```

But this is not effecting as because my output is coming like this:

Enter a Sentence:>We are Indians.
New String:>iNDIANS wE ARE 
To Continue Press 1 else press 0
Do you want to Continue:0

But I want the output Like this:
Enter a Sentence:>We are Indians.
New String:>iNDIANS wE ARE. 
To Continue Press 1 else press 0
Do you want to Continue:0

Comment: I suggest you use your debugger to debug your code.  If you step through the code line by line you will get a better understanding of why it does what it does and where it does something different to what you want.

Comment: Is the absence of the period here `New String:>iNDIANS wE ARE.` the only difference?

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your code before trying to find the error. Once simplified, it will be much easier. I suggest you to :

- replace your while (true) + break with do { } while (condition) for code readability
- use myString.split(' ') to count the words in the sentence
- use Arrays.sort on the result of myString.split(' ') to sort the words alphabetically
- use StringBuilder rather than String for your variable h in cse_Convert for performance

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a *lot* of code. So much, you can't tell what's going on.

These few lines are enough to get the job done:

```
String input = in.readLine();
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s+|(?=\\.)")));
Collections.sort(words);
String ordered = words.toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "").replacrAll("^\\.( .*)", "$0.");
```

The full stop is handled but expressly splitting it out, and because it will sort first, custom code to "move" it to the end if it exists.